# How to send WordPress form data via curl using POST?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I need to insert the following code into POST using CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.bmby.com/shared/AddClient/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://xxxxxxxx/');

$data = [
            'ProjectID' => xxxx
            'Password' => 'xxxxxx',
            'Fname' => $_POST['your-name'],
            'Email' => $_POST['email'],
            'Phone' => $_POST['your-tel'],
            #'Esse' => $_POST['msg'],
            'Referal' => 'http://xxxxxxxx/',
            'MediaTitle' => 'אתר אינטרנט ראשי',
            'AllowedMail' => 2, # 0 = allow, 2 = don't allow
            'IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any guidance on how to implement this and have the form that we created to relate to the above code so that the service we are using to gather all the leads from the form could get the required info.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of a form you have (it could be a .php file or a WP plugin), the above code needs to be in a function or a php file that will be executed when your form is submitted, either using the `action` attribute in the HTML form tag or in a function that's called using a form submit action/filter (which is common if you're using a plugin).

The code you posted, when correctly substituted with the correct variables (for example all the URLs and whatever you pass in `$data`) is the code for performing a cURL session using POST. Since `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set, `$output` will contain the result of the cURL session on success and FALSE on failure. Make sure that the POST variables like `$_POST['your-name']` correspond to the name attributes in your form fields. It is also recommended to validate the form fields instead of directly passing the `$_POST['your-name']`. Once you've edited the code with the correct variable names and URLs, the code should run and the result would be in your `$output`. You can check the result to see if it was a success or do something with the result as required. If you wish to get the HTTP code you should look into `curl_getinfo()`.